# How to create an interrupt divider using a DMAMUX on STM32 MCUs

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, stm32cubemx

I am trying to create an interrupt divider for an EXTI interrupt.
Essentially, instead of handling every interrupt, I want to call a handler once for every 10 interrupts.
After reading the reference manual of the STM32L4R5ZI that I am using, I can imagine a solution using the DMAMUX, which can count 10 requests on an EXTI line, and generate a single request when the counter reaches 0.

I am having trouble trying this in the STM32CubeIDE, and whould like some help understanding how the DMAMUX should be configured, and how to do this in HAL code.

Comment: Start with reading the DMAMUX chapter in RM, focus on _DMAMUX request generator_ subchapter. Set up input pin, its steering into EXTI in SYSCFG_EXTICR[], then set up the chosen DMAMUX according to the abovementioned chapter and set up the respective DMA channel as usually. You can split this task to setting up EXTI (and checking in EXTI itself if it does generate interrupts, although those are not needed for the DMAMUX to work), and you can set up DMA channel alone and check. If this can't be clicked in CubeMX, Cube/HAL won't really help and you are better off writing directly to registers.